# Can I use a larger hard drive with a product like docking station if it says it "supports hard drives up to 3TB"?

Tags: hard-drive, compatibility, docking-station, enclosures

In the description of [a hard drive docking station](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817392022) it says that "it supports hard drives up to 3TB". It supports both 2.5" and 3.5" HDDs.

If it supports drives "up to 3TB", does it mean that a 4 or 8 or larger TB HDD won't work with it? As long as the drive is a regular 2.5" or 3.5" HDD the way  it is connected is the same and so it should work, shouldn't it?

The question applies to other HDD products for example enclosures. I've also seen it stated that some support HDDs up to X TB.

In general, does it mean that a larger hard drive won't work or that only drives up to that capacity have been tested by the manufacturer to work with their product? Is buying such a product risky if I want to use it with a larger HDD than indented?

Comment: It will only allow you to access 3 TB of the hard disk; the rest would be unaccessible.

Comment: @Aganju Really? Why is that?

Comment: @MolexToSataLoseAllYourData - The SATA controller in your docking station does not support larger then 3TB drives

Comment: @Ramhound - your previous comment mentioned Windows but now you edited it. So it doesn't matter if it's Windows or Linux, more than 3TB won't work?

Comment: @MolexToSataLoseAllYourData - *My previous comment was deleted because it holds no relevance to your question.*

Comment: The correct answer is: Maybe. It’s not guaranteed, though.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.vantecusa.com/en/product/view_detail/295

I followed the link, and I think this is the manufacturers web site.

```
Install and Access Hard Drive in Seconds
Simple to Use Design; No Need to Add Enclosure or Open Case
Eject Button for Easy Removal of Hard Drive
**Compatible With Any 2.5” or 3.5” SATA I/II Hard Drive**
Add Storage to Any System with USB or eSATA
Plug & Play
Attractive Blue LED Power & HD Activity Light
Transfer Rates Up to 480Mbps w/USB 2.0
Transfer Rates Up to 3Gb/s w/SATA
```

It does say 3gb/s because of SATA 2, but it states ANY SATA 1/2 hdd.  However, after that is says  **HD Capacity:   Up to 4.0TB**